# $set not replacing values after $unwind and $match in a mongo aggregate query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, set, match

I am trying to find and update some fields in a nested array of objects. I am flattening the arrays with `$unwind` then use `$match` to isolate the instances I want to update, but `$set` doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I cannot use it in this way?

The two entries before attempting `$set`:

```
[
   {
     _id: 5dabcdf7501b3b4ab66f9f76,
     tasks: {
       _id: 5dabcde5c4a0ab4aa106af7d,
       task: '19',
       name: 'beyond',
       dimension: 'Transformational Leadership',
       subDimension: 'unknown',
       points: 1,
       imgUrl: 'imgs/19.svg',
       text: 'You completed a custom challenge!',
       userId: '5dabcdf7501b3b4ab66f9f76',
       createdAt: '48-Mo:01:48'
     },
     awards: [],
     firstName: 'bob',
     lastName: 'bob',
     location: 'Campbell, USA',
     unit: 'AMSBG',
     group: 3,
     team: 1,
     createdAt: 2019-10-20T03:01:11.071Z,
     updatedAt: 2019-10-29T16:03:54.002Z,
     no_of_tasks: 9,
     points: 9
   },
   {
     _id: 5dabcdf7501b3b4ab66f9f7d,
     tasks: {
       _id: 5dabcde5c4a0ab4aa106af7d,
       task: '19',
       name: 'beyond',
       dimension: 'Transformational Leadership',
       subDimension: 'unknown',
       points: 1,
       imgUrl: 'imgs/19.svg',
       text: 'You completed a custom challenge!',
       userId: '5dabcdf7501b3b4ab66f9f7d',
       createdAt: '48-Mo:01:48'
     },
     awards: [],
     firstName: 'bobette',
     lastName: 'bob',
     location: 'Taiperi',
     unit: 'Finance',
     group: 1,
     team: 1,
     createdAt: 2019-10-20T03:01:11.072Z,
     updatedAt: 2019-10-29T18:24:20.480Z,
     no_of_tasks: 40,
     points: 40
   }
 ]
```

the query as i thought it should work:

```
const tasks = await User.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$tasks' },
        { $match: {'tasks.name': foo.name} },
        { $set:
          {'tasks.text': foo.text,
          'tasks.subDimension': foo.subDimension }
        }
    ])
```

would love some insight as to why it is failing

Comment: When I run this I get the error `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'`

Comment: It is unclear what your intentions are.  Are you trying to modify the output of the query, or are you trying to update documents in the database?

Comment: By the way,  the $unwind is for flattening arrays, which I believe you commented on as well, but your example documents have one array but it is empty.  Attempts to unwind `$tasks` will have no effect since it is not an array.

Comment: I unwound the all the arrays across the collection and then selected only the matching two documents, which I am trying to update in the collection, not change the output.

Comment: You cannot update the collection with Aggregation. [$set (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) is an alias for $addFields.  Then, there is a [$set in update operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). Also, MongoDB 4.2 introduces Aggregation stages in `update`operations; see [db.collectionupdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Comment: There are 2 aggregation stages which allow the output to be written to another collection: `$merge` (in version 4.2 only) and `$out`. Refer here: [Aggregation stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-stages).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I should have been using `update()` and `arrayFillters`